# How to grant permission using FUNCTION in PostgreSQL 9.4.5

Tags: postgresql

I need to grant permissions to database users. i need to use FUNCTION to perform this.

```
grant all on schema schema1 to user1;
grant all on schema schema1 to user2;
grant all on schema schema1 to user3;
```

schema names and user names should be picked up from these sql query output:

```
select nspname from pg_namespace;

schema1
schema2
schema3

select usename from pg_user;

user1
user2
user3
```

could someone help me how to write a function to achive this ? i am using Postgresql 9.4.5.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grant_all()
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
    user TEXT;
    schema TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR user IN (SELECT usename FROM pg_user)
    LOOP
        FOR schema IN (SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace)
        LOOP
            EXECUTE format('GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA %s to %s', schema, user);
            RAISE NOTICE 'Granted all on % to %', schema, user;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```